# What happens in an operating theatre when a fire alarm goes off?

Tags: surgery, hospital

What happens in an operating theatre, during complex surgery that cannot be safely interrupted, when a fire alarm goes off and is not a test?

I assume that there is some sort of protocol in place?

Comment: What has your prior research revealed?

Comment: Some discussions on reddit and DS but no definitive answer from an informed source.